# Row counts across aggregated tables

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple tables in a postgres database that hold perfectly unique information.  The information, when properly joined together in a query, will produce all every possible combination that I'm looking.  The information I'm looking for are complete SKUs.

To generate a complete SKUs, this query produces the desired results:
**Functional Query**

```
SELECT
    materials.code,
    "part_base_parts".code as part_base_parts_id,
    shanks.code AS shank_id,
    measurements.description
FROM
    "part_base_parts"
LEFT JOIN "part_types" ON "part_base_parts"."part_type_id" = "part_types"."id"
RIGHT JOIN "parts_to_shanks" ON "part_base_parts"."id" = "parts_to_shanks"."part_base_part_id"
RIGHT JOIN "parts_to_measurements" ON "part_base_parts"."id" = "parts_to_measurements"."part_base_part_id"
RIGHT JOIN "parts_to_materials" ON "part_base_parts"."id" = "parts_to_materials"."part_base_part_id"
JOIN materials ON "parts_to_materials"."material_id" = materials."id"
JOIN shanks ON "parts_to_shanks"."shank_id" = shanks."id"
JOIN measurements ON "parts_to_measurements"."measurement_id" = measurements."id"
ORDER BY
    part_base_parts_id ASC,
    materials.code ASC,
    shank_id ASC,
    measurements.description ASC
```

Given this query, I produce 32,640 records (without indexing applied) with a query time of .82 seconds.  Something like this...

**Given Output**

```
code    part_base_parts_id  shank_id    description
AA      5105                A           03.0
.
. 32,638 rows in here.
.
ST      6939                D           9/16
```

This is only getting me half way there, though.  I need to take the results back from the query and produce the total number of counts from each column.  So the result that I need to have would be:

**Desired Results**

```
code: AA - ###0
      ...
      ST - ###0
part_base_parts_id: 5105 - ###0
                    ...
                    6939 - ###0
shank_id: A - ###0
          ...
          D - ###0
description: 03.0 - ###0
             ...
             9/16 - ###0
```

Is there a way to produce the **"desired results"** from Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them in rows then sure.

```
WITH cte AS(    
    SELECT
        materials.code,
        "part_base_parts".code as part_base_parts_id,
        shanks.code AS shank_id,
        measurements.description
    FROM
        "part_base_parts"
    LEFT JOIN "part_types" ON "part_base_parts"."part_type_id" = "part_types"."id"
    RIGHT JOIN "parts_to_shanks" ON "part_base_parts"."id" = "parts_to_shanks"."part_base_part_id"
    RIGHT JOIN "parts_to_measurements" ON "part_base_parts"."id" = "parts_to_measurements"."part_base_part_id"
    RIGHT JOIN "parts_to_materials" ON "part_base_parts"."id" = "parts_to_materials"."part_base_part_id"
    JOIN materials ON "parts_to_materials"."material_id" = materials."id"
    JOIN shanks ON "parts_to_shanks"."shank_id" = shanks."id"
    JOIN measurements ON "parts_to_measurements"."measurement_id" = measurements."id"
    ORDER BY
        part_base_parts_id ASC,
        materials.code ASC,
        shank_id ASC,
        measurements.description ASC    
)
SELECT key, value, count(*)
FROM(
  SELECT 'code' AS key, code AS value
  FROM cte
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'part_base_parts_id', code
  FROM cte
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'shank_id', shank_id
  FROM cte
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'description',  description
  FROM cte
) AS q
GROUP BY key, value
ORDER BY key, value
```

Comment: Lack of one `UNION ALL`. I'd add `ORDER BY key, value`.

Comment: I've fixed the copy/paste errors and added ORDER BY as per @klin 's suggestion.

Comment: That query worked @jakub-kania and @klin!  I did take a hit on the query time.  Coming from .82 seconds up to ~3.7 seconds for the final results.  I'll research indexes and see what table to apply them to, and how that might impact the query.  Thoughts on increase the performance time?

Comment: @JakubKania, you wrote above "If you want them in rows then sure."  Are there other ways of getting the data?

Comment: @JeffNichols Well, you could get them as a json document or arrays. You could also go for columns but that will will be really weird and impractical. You could speed up the query by moving the group by to unioned selects (I didn't to save on writing). Otherwise then that you can only try to increse the work_mem or  speed up the original query or but we need the explain plan to help with that.